# Excel: find most common value of each group

Tags: microsoft-excel, mode

I have data in the following format:

```
YEAR    CABINET
2017    Cabinet A
2016    Cabinet A
2016    Cabinet A
2014    Cabinet B
2014    Cabinet B
2013    Cabinet B
```

These are the values for files in each cabinet. I want to find out which cabinet contains mostly which year's files. So my intended result is something like this:

```
Cabinet A: 2016
Cabinet B: 2014
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot? the question's formatting is making it difficult to understand your question.

Comment: some sample data would help, this sounds doable with a little array formula

Comment: Now the formatting is correct. Please see the question again

Comment: @Usman See answer below

Answer (score 2):

Use the below, and enter it using Ctrl + Shift + Enter to wrap it in curly brackets {}

```
=MODE(IF($B:$B=C2,$A:$A))
```

Assuming **YEAR** is in Column A

**Cabinet** is in Column B

Then the Cabinet Types in Column C : 'Cabinet A' in C2 and 'Cabinet B' in C3 etc

Your **MODE** would then go in D2 and drag down